# how to call web service from prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

I have a web service that is created by using java (jsp and servlet).Now I need to call this web service by using prolog.

For Example: in prolog, `?:getUserCategory(username)`.
 then prolog will call web service with these parameters.
*Please help me how to do this?*

NB;web service is running on tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mProlog for Web related project. This is a light weighted Prolog Engine.
[mProLog](http://www.cs.uu.nl/3apl-m/mprolog.html)

You can also edit this Engine according to your requirement.